# Precompiled Header with Constants issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, constants, prefix, undeclared-identifier

I have a few constants files "Constants.h" in my project that I am including in the Prefix.pch file to be available to all the classes in my project. They just contain a bunch of #define statements.

My classes don't recognize these constants (no autocomplete) and Xcode gives me "Undeclared Identifier" errors every time I use them. However when I run the project everything works fine (set to ignore errors).

Is there any way I can get rid of these warnings? #pragma ignore them in the prefix file or something? I've tried many options, including setting "precompile prefix header" to NO in build settings.

Any ideas?

EDIT: 
I have tried deleting derived data and cleaning / deleting build folder to no avail.

It might be worth noting that I have 3 targets in my project, and another project within this project.

Also, some of the #imports import normal classes. Like a category extension on UIFont and an Analytics class. Could this affect it?

Comment: "Undeclared identifier" is an error, not a warning. You cannot compile and run a program using undeclared identifiers.

Comment: Edited to correct that, I meant error. I have it set to ignore errors so the program still compiles and runs fine, xcode just gives me these errors when I'm editing code.

Comment: And it doesn't recognize them right away after building, usually only when i'm inside a class that uses those constants does it start seeing the 'errors'

Comment: What exactly have you set to "ignore errors"? You cannot compile and run a program containing errors.

Comment: it's better to "answer your own question" than to edit the question itself and mark it as "solved", so that it doesn't appear in the "unanswered questions" list.

Comment: I couldn't answer my own question because it wouldn't let me, because "new users cannot answer their own questions within 4 hours of posting"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a preprocessor macro in one of my targets that I moved from 'preprocessor macros' to 'preprocessor macros not used in precompiled headers' and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 10):

To fix this, I had to change the 'Precompile Prefix Header' flag to NO in my target's Build Settings. By doing this you'll lose any build performance achieved by having a cached compiled header file, but in my case, my Prefix Header is pretty small so I wont see a hit in the time it takes to build.

Comment: This solved it for me as well, but it does make compiling substantially slower. Any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting the project derived data. Xcode sometimes needs to re-index your project to remove "errors" such as this.

Organizer > Projects > Your Project

Click on the "Delete" button to the right of the Derived Data row.

Immediately quit Xcode, and then reopen.

Comment: Have tried that many times. Also tried deleting build folder, cleaning etc. Keeps coming back.

Comment: Solved my problem i was stuck on in for an hour.

Answer (score 2):

I had the PCH file importing .h file with a lot of macros (specifically, I use the [MJGAvailability](https://github.com/mattjgalloway/MJGFoundation/blob/master/Source/Utilities/MJGAvailability.h) header that warns when I use features that are newer than my deployment target).
Replacing:

```
#import "MJGAvailability.h"
```

with

```
#include "MJGAvailability.h"
```

solved this issue for me.